# How to go about create and manage user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on a job portal. I am confused on how I should create and manage users. For example: there will be 3 types of users(which may expand later) in my application: Company, Consultancy, and Candidates. Each of them will have a completely different role and access to the admin(i.e. account) panel/console, or you can say they will have a completely different views for managing their account. So, if a user logs in with a company account, he/she should be able to create jobs and update company profile, if a user logs in as a consultant then he/ she should be able post jobs on behalf of other companies(who may or may not be registered on the website/app) and should also be to surf/ search the jobs from companies and should be able to post applications(i.e. apply for a job) of candidates on candidates(who may or may not be registered yet on the website/app) behalf. And, if a user logs in as a candidate then he/she should be able to create their resumes/ cvs, search jobs, and apply for jobs posted by companies.

Here is what I'd thought: Create a User model and then have STI(Single table inheritance) for Company, Consultancy, and Candidate. But, STI gets complicated sooner than later. Later, I thought of creating different models for each, but then code will be repeated for login/ signups and other similar activities, which means no DRY.

I would like to follow the best approach possible. So, would like to know how experts will go about solving such a scenario? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Look at the CanCan gem for user roles.
- Look at devise for a login system where you can login users.
- You can use active admin gem to create an administration backend ( crud, create remove update delete ) users. Or build an admin backend yourself
- Also checkout railscasts.com ( theres a cast on cancan and devise also!) for general ruby on rails tips and tricks. http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan
- Checkout "micheal hartl ruby on rails course " for some general understanding of how models, controllers and views all relate to each other.

Comment: thanks for your time, much appreciated. I know about cancan and devise. I am little confused on what should I do? use STI and put roles accordingly? or create different models all together and have roles on them accordingly?

Comment: You can create a User model, and have a attribute User.role ( default cancan usage) then you can use that field to set the role of the user regular/admin/manager/vip and set permissions with an ability.rb model. See http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan It will take away most of your questions. Good luck!

Comment: I got the answers by watching this railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations